# Using The RedditAPI I am trying to display posts in a listview but the listview is showing object reference

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to pass the redditposts to an ArrayList and display them, I have converted the JSON string and have a redditpost class. But When I add them to the ArrayList I only get the object reference.

The redditPost Class goes off the reddithelper class and converts a son string to a string

I am very new to java and android so if I don't understand your answer please be patient with me

Comment: Can you show us the `RedditPost` class? The ListView doesn't know how to display a `RedditPost` and just calls `toString()`. Either create a custom adapter for `RedditPost` or convert the list to a `List<String>` by inserting `redditPost.getTitle()` values from the `RedditPost` list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ArrayAdapter expects that calling `toString()` on the list element will return the title to be displayed. So either override `toString()` in your element class or pass a `List<String>`.

Overriding `toString()`:

```
public class RedditPost {

    public String id;
    public String title;
    public String url;

    public RedditPost(String id,String title, String url){
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return this.title;
    }
}
```

Convert the list to a `List<String>`:

```
public void setarraylist(){
    string json = JsonString
    ArrayList<RedditPost> posts = RedditPostHelper.getRedditPostsFromJSON(json);
    Posts_Array_List.clear();
    for (RedditPost post : posts) {
         Posts_Array_List.add(post.title);
    }
}
```

And of course change the `Posts_Array_List` type to a `ArrayList<String>` and the adapter to a `ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: If it's not too much trouble would you know how I would go about making the list item's direct to the URL?

Comment: @Bats I recommend reading up some basic tutorials about ListViews with an adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your class with the following.

```
public class RedditPost {

    public String id;
    public String title;
    public String url;

    public RedditPost(String id,String title, String url){
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.url = url;
    }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return this.title;          
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks so much :D

Comment: If it's not too much trouble would you know how I would go about making the list item's direct to the URL?